# How do I resolve the error EPERM error when running npx create-next-app@latest?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

I tried to run the create app to get started with react and received the below error. I figured it is because react does not have the rights to drive D: but that is just a guess.

Please help me understand or provide documentation that could resolve I am super new to development so be patient with me.

Thank you.

> Aborting installation. Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
> [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\React\vita'] {
> errno: -4048,   code: 'EPERM',   syscall: 'mkdir',   path:
> 'D:\React\vita' }

Answer (score -2):

The error message you're encountering, "EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir," typically indicates that the installation process doesn't have the necessary permissions to create a directory at the specified location, in this case, 'D:\React\vita.' This is indeed related to file system permissions.

Here are some steps to resolve this issue:

1. **Run as Administrator:** The most common reason for this error is that you don't have the necessary permissions to create directories in the 'D:' drive. Try running the installation as an administrator. Right-click on the command prompt or terminal and select "Run as administrator." This should grant the necessary permissions to create directories.
2. **Use a Different Directory:** If you still encounter issues even with administrator privileges, try creating your React project in a different directory that you have write permissions for. You can use a directory on your system drive (e.g., 'C:\React\vita').
3. **Check User Permissions:** Ensure that your user account has the necessary permissions to create directories and files on the 'D:' drive. You can check this by right-clicking on the 'D:' drive in Windows Explorer, selecting "Properties," and going to the "Security" tab.
4. **Antivirus or Security Software:** Sometimes, antivirus or security software can block file operations. Check if any such software might be interfering with the creation of directories.
5. **Reinstall Node.js and npm:** If you've encountered this issue after installing Node.js and npm, try reinstalling them. Make sure you download the latest version from the official website (https://nodejs.org/) and follow the installation instructions.
6. **Use a Package Manager:** Instead of using the `create-react-app` command directly, you can try using a package manager like Yarn or npm with npx to create the React app. For example:

   ```bash
   npx create-react-app@latest my-react-app
   ```

   This might help avoid permission issues because it uses a temporary directory for the installation.

check this, it may helpful!

Comment: `npx create-next-app@latest`